# Is there a way to use ADAL.js to add "domain_hint=exampledomain.com" to https://login.microsoftonline.com url in angular js code?

Tags: angularjs, azure-active-directory, adal.js

We are trying to authenticate users in our custom application with Azure AD in a similar manner as shown in this article. (https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) When the user goes to that application, they are routed to https://login.microsoftonline.com, where they have to put in their email address. Then, they are routed to our federation endpoint which is PingFederate. However, we want our users to be directly routed to PingFederate, without having them go to login.microsoftonline.com. This article (https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2015/02/11/using-azure-ad-to-land-users-on-their-custom-login-page-from-within-your-app/) says to append "&domain_hint=exampledomain.com" to the login.microsoftonline url to allow the user to skip the step of putting in email in login.microsoftonline page. We have tested this by manually adding "&domain_hint=exampledomain.com" to login.microsoftonline.com url, and it works. However, we want a way to add this variable in our code so that this is done automatically. We tried adding domain_hint variable and value to adalAuthenticationServiceProvider.init object in angular js code but this didnt work. How can we add "domain_hint=exampledomain.com" to the login.microsoftonline url so that the user doesnt have to visit the microsoft login page, and is directly routed to PingFederate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've achieved this outcome for Angular 4 using adal-angular4 library (Angular 4 wrapper for adaljs); with following configuration in app.component.ts file. I'm pretty sure it will work with all similar versions. The key here is **you need to add your domain hint as extra query parameter for configuration of adal** which will be sent to the request.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { adal } from 'adal-angular';
import { Adal4Service } from 'adal-angular4';

const config: adal.Config = {                           
    tenantId: 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    clientId: 'abcdabcd-abcd-abcd-abcd-abcdabcdabcd',
    domain: 'my-domain.net',
    extraQueryParameter: 'domain_hint=my-domain.co.uk',
}                                                    

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'My Angular 4 App';

  constructor(private service: Adal4Service) {    
    this.service.init(config);                    
  }                                              
}
```